# Learn Python the Hard Way ex20, how does this function work?

Tags: python

I'm learning python without any prior experience about coding and this is something I now do not understand.

Here's the whole code:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

The last part should print like this:

```
Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1 This is line 1
2 This is line 2
3 This is line 3
```

The part I don't understand is those last few lines. How does the "current_file" block understand that it must firstly print only one line and secondly how does it know that it should be the same line as the "current_line" want's it?

Answer (score 3):

A file object advances every time you call `.readline()` on it; the `current_line` variable is only used to give you a line number. The two are not really related.

Try removing the `current_line = current_line + 1` lines, and it'll print:

```
Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.
Let's print three lines:
1 This is line 1
1 This is line 2
1 This is line 3
```

You can imagine `current_line` to be your own personal notepad keeping a count, just to verify that the lines are indeed advancing. If you forget to write down the next number, the file doesn't care and moves on regardless.

A file is very much like a tape; every time you read from it, the read-write 'head' advances along the 'tape' so that the next read or write action takes place at that new location.

The 'head' is just a number, the position in the file, managed by the operating system. You can always ask a file for the current position with the [`file.tell()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell). If you add `print f.tell()` lines to the `print_a_line()` function, it'll print where the head is positioned at that moment.

Last but not least, as the `rewind()` function already shows, the [`file.seek()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) lets you reposition the 'head' to a new location. `f.seek(0)` puts it back a the start.